# How to boot FreeBSD from GNU GRUB 2 bootloader command mode

Tags: freebsd, grub2

I've been following an installation guide for FreeBSD and this part seems to be skipped. When I reboot my system after the initial installation it loads to grub boot loader, but in command mode as no options have been setup yet. I have windows10 installed on another drive.

How do I load FreeBSD from this command mode?

Comment: yeah, it says: 'GNU GRUB version 2.02' 'Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported...' and then 'grub>'

Answer (score 4):

Run `ls` to list the partitions and replace `hd0,X` with your root partition:

```
set root=(hd0,X)
kfreebsd /boot/kernel/kernel
boot
```

Comment: error: can't find command 'root'

Comment: the kernel command doesn't seem to work for me either

Comment: @koko use `kfreebsd` instead of `kernel`

Comment: can't find 'kfreebsd' either, have I missed something during installation?

Comment: @koko here is how to boot freebsd from grub2 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2%20Other%20Os#Direct_Kernel_Boot .`kfreebsd` is a grub command.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I am still getting the error 'can't find command 'kfreebsd''

Comment: @koko is freebsd installed on multiboot with linux?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to install [GRUB2WIN](https://sourceforge.net/p/grub2win/).
I have a similar setup; FreeBSD multi-booted with GNU/Linux.

For EFI hardware:

```
set root=(hdX,Y)
chainloader /boot/loader.efi
boot
```

For non-EFI hardware:

```
set root=(hdX,Y)
kfreebsd /boot/loader
boot
```

For EFI hardware + ZFS:

```
set root=(hdX,Y)
chainloader /@/boot/loader.efi
boot
```

For non-EFI hardware + ZFS:

```
set root=(hdX,Y)
kfreebsd /@/boot/loader
boot
```

All of these methods work for me, and I hope they do for you, too.

[image]

[image]